# Backbone.js event after view.render() is finished

Tags: backbone.js

Does anyone know which event is fired after a view is rendered in backbone.js?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As far as I know - [none is fired](http://backbonejs.org/#View-render). Render function is empty in source code.

> The default implementation of render is a no-op

I would recommend just triggering it manually when necessary.

Comment: @StefanSchmidt btw - try reading backbone.js source code yourself. it's quite readable.

Comment: yeah ... thats what i figured out after your post. before I was a little bit scared. kinda javascript noob :D

Answer (score 38):

I ran into this [post](http://fahad19.tumblr.com/post/28158699664/afterrender-callback-in-backbone-js-views) which seems interesting

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({ 

    initialize: function(options) { 
        _.bindAll(this, 'beforeRender', 'render', 'afterRender'); 
        var _this = this; 
        this.render = _.wrap(this.render, function(render) { 
            _this.beforeRender(); 
            render(); 
            _this.afterRender(); 
            return _this; 
        }); 
    }, 

    beforeRender: function() { 
       console.log('beforeRender'); 
    }, 

    render: function() { 
        return this; 
    }, 

    afterRender: function() { 
        console.log('afterRender'); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: Why do you need this line: `_.bindAll(this, 'beforeRender', 'render', 'afterRender');`?

Comment: @pilau - Refer [this](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2011/08/18/understanding-bind-and-bindall-in-backbone.html) for understanding _.bind and _.bindAll. It helped me, hope it would help you too.

Comment: I know what it does, I am inquiring about why you require using it at all, since they (the functions), are all extending the view object anyway?

Comment: Just to help clarify: To add your own functions to the model and collection, you have to use bindAll.  This is not the case for the view they are 'bound' automatically.

Comment: @JohnMoses Exactly my point, they are already part of the View object

Comment: @abritez How can I get this working if I want to pass parameters to render function? If I change the definition to ```render: function(opts)``` I can't access ```opts``` object.

Comment: If you dont use `Function.prototype.bind`, `_.bind`, or `_.bindAll`, the context of `render()` will be `window`

Answer (score 24):

Or you can do the following, which is what Backbone code is supposed to look like (Observer pattern, aka pub/sub). This is the way to go:

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({ 
    initialize: function() {  
        this.on('render', this.afterRender);

        this.render();
    },

    render: function () {  
        this.trigger('render');
    },

    afterRender: function () {
    }
});
```

Edit: `this.on('render', 'afterRender');` will not work - because `Backbone.Events.on` accepts only functions. The `.on('event', 'methodName');` magic is made possible by `Backbone.View.delegateEvents` and as such is only available with DOM events.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object afterRender has no method 'call'

Comment: @Trip Fixed. Didn't think it would matter but apparently it doesn't work with the name of the method alone. I now have to find out why.

Comment: @PHPst: What is the purpose of your edit, i.e. changing `render` to show`?

Comment: @PHPst: The custom event being triggered is named `render`, as in `this.trigger('render');`. Where are you getting `show` from? Do you have a link to some documentation? As far as I know, there is no  Backbone event called `show`.

Comment: @PHPst Your edit completely breaks my code, you see that line `this.trigger('render');`? Well, because I'm registering `this.afterRender` on the `render` event (a custom event, not part of Backbone), `this.afterRender` will get fired after the template is rendered. I don't know why did you make that edit, by I'm reverting it. By the way, the word "show" doesn't even appear in the Backbone annotated source...

Comment: @pilau I wonder why `render` do not work for my but `show` works. I will investigate on it.

Comment: @PHPst Great, let us know!

Comment: After trying a ton of fixes, this one worked out best for me. Thanks pilau

Comment: @GONeale Sure buddy :) The correct way is always the best way!

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to be using [Marionette](http://marionettejs.com/), Marionette adds `show` and `render` events on views.  See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18167517/132374) for an example.

On a side note, Marionette adds a lot of other useful features that you might be interested in.

Answer (score 1):

I realise this question is fairly old but I wanted a solution that allowed the same custom function to be called after every call to `render`, so came up with the following...

First, override the default Backbone `render` function:

```
var render = Backbone.View.prototype.render;
Backbone.View.prototype.render = function() {
    this.customRender();
    afterPageRender();
    render();
};
```

The above code calls `customRender` on the view, then a generic custom function (`afterPageRender`), then the original Backbone `render` function.

Then in my views, I replaced all instances of `render` functions with `customRender`:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.listenTo(this.model, 'sync', this.render);
    this.model.fetch();
},

customRender: function() {
    // ... do what you usually do in render()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of adding the eventhandler manually to render on intialization you can also add the event to the 'events' section of your view. See http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents

e.g.

```
events: {
   'render': 'afterRender'
}

afterRender: function(e){
    alert("render complete")
},
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Delegate Events refer to events that occur on the dom.  Not callbacks on the view object itself.

Comment: `events` is used for `declarative callbacks for DOM events`, see [backbone/#View-delegateEvents](http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/#View-delegateEvents)

Answer (score -3):

```
 constructor: function(){
   Backbone.View.call(this, arguments);     
   var oldRender = this.render
   this.render = function(){
      oldRender.call(this)
      // this.model.trigger('xxxxxxxxx')
   }       
 }
```

like this  http://jsfiddle.net/8hQyB/

Comment: You do not need to overwrite the `constructor` for this.

Comment: Constructor isn't the point. you also can trigger it manual or use  jquery $.Deferred. @cept0