# How to bind a HTML element as soon as it is rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a span in my view which is rendered using Backbone.js

I want to get its HTML as soon as its rendered

Something like : `$(span).html()`

How can I do this?

Comment: Please see [Backbone.js event after view.render() is finished](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790361/backbone-js-event-after-view-render-is-finished). See if that adds some insight. Also, I'd recommend adding more details to your question if that doesn't help clarify some things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question confused me a bit, because Backbone.View doesn't actually have a `render` method at all (well, technically it does but its a no-op); it's 100% user-defined.  Given that fact, checking ... well, *anything* after you render is as simple as ... well, checking it after you render.

In other words, if your view's render method is:

```
var YourView= Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(someHtml);
    }
});
```

Then all you need to do is:

```
var YourView= Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(someHtml);
        console.log(this.$el.html()); // check rendered HTML
    }
});
```

If you want to intermediate that with events you could (as @aerodynamo suggested):

```
var YourView= Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {'customPostRender': 'postRender'},
    postRender: function() {
        console.log(this.$el.html()); // check rendered HTML
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(someHtml);
        this.trigger('customPostRender');
    }
});
```

but really that's not even necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver) helps, but definitely worth to check out:-)