# Backbone view event after html template rendered

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I want to call some function after html is rendered in all view. So, I want some event which is raised after backbone view is rendered. Is there any existing event or how do I make my own event using view extending?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Backbone.js event after view.render() is finished](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790361/backbone-js-event-after-view-render-is-finished)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do something like

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend(Backbone.Events, {
  // usual code (template, etc.)

  render: function(){
    // code to render view

    // trigger event
    this.trigger("render:after", "View rendered !");
  }
});
```

Then, to react to the event:

```
var view = new MyView(...);
view.listenTo(view, "render:after", function(msg){
  alert(msg);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this :

```
var render = Backbone.View.prototype.render;

Backbone.View.prototype.render = function() {
    var rendered = render();
    this.trigger("render", this);
    return rendered;
}
```

So whenever a view is rendered the render event will be triggered. And you don't need to everytime you extend the `Backbone.View` to add the `this.trigger("render..`