# How can I get clientHeight value outside backbone render function?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, scroll

I using [zynga scroller](http://github.com/zynga/scroller/blob/master/src/EasyScroller.js) javascript for scrolling in backbone web-app but clientHeight of rendered element is always 0.
This is because script for scrolling is loaded and executed before backbone render method.

```
    render: function(){
        var persons = this.model;
        var personsCollection = new PersonsCollection(persons);
        this.el.innerHTML = _.template( personsTemplate,{data : _.groupBy(personsCollection.toJSON(), 'status')} );
        console.log(this.el.clientHeight);  // ========= 1500
        new EasyScroller(this.el, {scrollingX: false, scrollingY: true});
    },
```

Is possible to execute loading of scroller javascript after render? Or any other solutions?
**From scrolling script:**

```
EasyScroller.prototype.reflow = function() {

    this.scroller.setDimensions(this.container.clientWidth, this.container.clientHeight, this.content.offsetWidth, this.content.offsetHeight);

};
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Have you added `data-scrollable="y"` attribute to the view's el element?

Comment: @ManishMulimani Yes I have. Scroll efect is working but only efect not scrolling. Page has behavior like overflow hide. If I change attribute clientHeight in javascript to specific value (example 1200) everything is working like I want, but you know height is set manualy and I need it variable....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how [EasyScroller](http://zynga.github.io/scroller/src/EasyScroller.js) functionality is added:

When the document is fully loaded and parsed, the document is searched for all elements with data attributes `data-scrollable` and `data-zoomable`. For each such element, `EasyScroller` instance is created, which adds the scrolling functionality.

In Backbone applications, since we modify the dom tree, we need to create the `EasyScroller` instance explicitly.

After assigning content to `Backbone view`'s `el` element, you can dynamically attach the `EasyScroller` to it. You need not add `data-scrollable` attribute to the `el` element, with this approach.

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'], function($, _, Backbone) {
    var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: _.template("<div data-i18n='view.name'></div>"),
        render: function() {
            this.$el.html(this.template);

            // Now attach the EasyScroller element to the el element.
            new EasyScroller(this.el, {scrollingX: false, scrollingY: true});
        }
    });

    return HomeView;
});
```

Comment: I have edited my code. My render function is like your and I have already removed `data-scrollable="y"` from content element. Now I see same `bug` efect is working but page did not scroll.

Comment: @Makromat I've committed my code in [github](https://github.com/manishcm/easyscroller). You can check it out.

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working better. Look to my repository [Github](https://github.com/makromat/app) Page has never-ending scroll function...without end... Do you have idea why ?

Comment: @Makromat I've git cloned your app and made changes in the [clone repo](https://github.com/manishcm/app). Issue was solved by applying styling to the div element to which easy scroller functionality will be attached.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Manish Mulimani, it is working but, is possible to do it without set height of container? Thanks

Comment: @Makromat I will check and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Found this piece of code, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13776776/3561555) and [here](http://fahad19.tumblr.com/post/28158699664/afterrender-callback-in-backbone-js-views)

Basically wraps beforeRender() and afterRender() to the default render function and extends them so you can write some code to be executed when you need it. Scope is the same as render scope. GL!

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({ 

  initialize: function(options) { 
    _.bindAll(this, 'beforeRender', 'render', 'afterRender'); 
    var _this = this; 
    this.render = _.wrap(this.render, function(render) { 
      _this.beforeRender(); 
      render(); 
      _this.afterRender(); 
      return _this; 
    }); 
  }, 

  beforeRender: function() { 
    console.log('beforeRender'); 
  }, 

  render: function() { 
    return this; 
  }, 

  afterRender: function() { 
    console.log('afterRender'); 
  } 
});
```