# Dom elements not updated when accessed inside backbone afterRender()

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, render, backbone-views, backbone-events

Here is my render() function:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.selectDivView = new SelectView({
        url: '/ir/secure/api/v40/myvariants/myVariantDBs',
        method: 'POST',
        template: myVariantDBFilterTemplate
     });
},

render: function() {
    this.$el.html(template()); //has div for "select drop down"
    this.selectDivView.setElement(this.$(this._selectDivId)).render();
    this.afterRender();
},

afterRender: function() {
    this.$(this._selectEl).val();
    //Expected to get some value but the select control is not yet rendered in dom
}
```

I tried doing it in the way mentioned at this link
[Backbone.js event after view.render() is finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790361/backbone-js-event-after-view-render-is-finished) but was not able to access DOM elements.

Here is my Select control's handlebar template selectDiv.html

```
{{#each filters}}
<option value="{{id}}">{{name}}</option>
{{/each}}
```

I guess the DOM is not refreshed by the time I am in afterRender(). What can be done here ?

My render function of SelectDivView

```
render: function(selectedValue) {
    this.selectedValue = selectedValue;
        $.ajax({
            url: this.url,
            method: this.method,
            async: false,  // THIS IS THE DECIDING PROPERTY.
            success: function(data) {
                    that.filters = data;
                    that._doRender.call(that);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Maybe you're doing something asynchronous in `selectDivView`'s `render` method..?We can't tell for sure unless we see the code.  Please share [mcve]

Comment: @t-j Thank you so much.  Your statement "Maybe you're doing something asynchronous in selectDivView's render method"gave me the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding ajax property

```
async: false
```

in render function of selectDivView solved the problem.

Here is how the render function of select div will look like

```
render: function(selectedValue) {
    this.selectedValue = selectedValue;
        $.ajax({
            url: this.url,
            method: this.method,
            async: false,  // THIS IS THE DECIDING PROPERTY.
            success: function(data) {
                    that.filters = data;
                    that._doRender.call(that);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Hi, synchronous ajax requests are deprecated... You should be seeing a warning in the developer tools if yo're using latest versions of browsers like chrome... Better return the xhr object and access the value once the request succeeds

Answer (score -1):

Did you bind afterRender manually?

```
initialize: function(options) { 
  _.bindAll(this, 'beforeRender', 'render', 'afterRender'); 
  var _this = this; 
  this.render = _.wrap(this.render, function(render) { 
    _this.beforeRender(); 
    render(); 
    _this.afterRender(); 
  });
},

render: function() {
    this.$el.html(template()); //has div for "select drop down"
    this.selectDivView.setElement(this.$(this._selectDivId)).render();
    return this;
},

afterRender: function() {
    this.$(this._selectEl).val();
}
```

Comment: This is what exactly I did. But inside after render the select  control was not yet rendered with the options.

Comment: I see. When you stop inside of afterRender, can you find the select control using the console? Or is it just not rendered at all?

Comment: I can see the select control in console. But it is not rendered with options. But once I am out of the afterRender() on my browser I can see the select control properly with all values.

Comment: Tried. It's not working. I guess this is what you suggested before also.